# Scala REPL in Eclipse does not see my own classes

Tags: eclipse, scala, interpreter, scala-ide

I created a Java / Maven project in Eclipse, and added the Scala nature. Eclipse can compile my Scala classes (when they are correct), but if I create a Scala interpreter in the project, I cannot import my classes in it. It says my root package does not exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your classes in the default package?

Comment: No, I use the usual reversed-domain-name scheme for my packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work correctly in the latest version of Scala Eclipse Plugin (2.0.0.beta09). Do you still have the problem?

Comment: Latest version is actually beta10.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Just for the records. I'm not sure why it didn't work when I first posted this. But I know why it doesn't work now.

If I have *any* error at all in my Scala code, in *any* source file, the compiler doesn't produce *any* compiled class at all! This is totally different from Java. I am programming Java at work, and I'm often running apps in workspaces where a dozen of irrelevant files don't compile without problems.

I find this a very strange behavior. I can't imagine any of our developer PCs being powerful enough to compile 1.6M lines of (Java) code *in memory* before writing the class files to disk.